# High time until SSH asks for password

Tags: ssh, networking, ping, delay

I've been noting recently that any host that I ssh to in LAN, waits like 5 seconds before asking for password.

`ping` sometimes also waits, but less(like 2 seconds), but it shows it has resolved the address correctly.

`nslookup` resolves very fast with my local dns.

Question is, how could I debug this?

Edit:

In ssh, it has a delay between these lines:

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
```

Comment: `ssh -v -v -v` might be a good start

Comment: @thrig yes you are right, I missed it. I updated

Comment: Sometimes this happens when the DNS on the remote system is slow at mapping the client's IP address to a FQDN. After you login to the remote system, try `nslookup` with your client's numeric IP address and see if that takes awhile.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ssh -v` on originating system, check `/var/log/*` on target. Try timing access by IP address as well as by hostname.